# How to use Django's filesizeformat

Tags: python, django

I have a small app I'm working on where I'm trying to use Django's built in filesizeformat.  Currently, the format looks like this: `{{ value|filesizeformat }}`.  I understand I need to define this in my view.py file but, I can't seem to figure out how to do that.  I've tried to use the syntax below:

```
def filesizeformat(bytes):
    """
    Formats the value like a 'human-readable' file size (i.e. 13 KB, 4.1 MB,
    102 bytes, etc).
    """
    try:
        bytes = float(bytes)
    except (TypeError,ValueError,UnicodeDecodeError):
        return u"0 bytes"

    if bytes < 1024:
        return ungettext("%(size)d byte", "%(size)d bytes", bytes) % {'size': bytes}
    if bytes < 1024 * 1024:
        return ugettext("%.1f KB") % (bytes / 1024)
    if bytes < 1024 * 1024 * 1024:
        return ugettext("%.1f MB") % (bytes / (1024 * 1024))
    return ugettext("%.1f GB") % (bytes / (1024 * 1024 * 1024))
filesizeformat.is_safe = True
```

I've then replaced 'value' with 'bytes' in the template but, this does not seem to work.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`filesizeformat` is a **built-in**  filter, you do not need to implement it yourself. You should provide the value into the template, for example:

```
{% for page in pages %}
    <li>page.name {{page.size|filesizeformat}}</li>
{% endfor %}
```

Now when you render the template from the view provide a `pages` argument which is a list of dicts like:

```
[{'name': 'page1', 'size': 10000}, {'name': 'page2', 'size': 5023034}]
```

And so on.

Comment: Eli,

Thanks for the info.  Much appreciated.  Worked like a charm for me.

Comment: @Eli When i use the tag {{maxSize|filesizeformat}}, nothing shows up whereas if I use {{maxSize}} (which is passed in through the context), the size in bytes does show up?  Any ideas why this would be?  Is there something I have to put somewhere to load the filesizeformat filter?